# R: Contingency table shows 0 counts for categorical data

Tags: r, statistics

I want to perform a chi-square test on categorical data to see if there are any differences. there are 3 groups and each group can have an item that can be 1 of 19 different types.

data example:

| Group1 | Group2 | Group3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TypeA |  | TypeP |
|  | TypeB |  |

```
head(df)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 3
```

|  | Group1 | Group2 | Group3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |
| 1 | NA | NA | NA |
| 2 | NA | TypeH | NA |
| 3 | NA | TypeE | NA |
| 4 | NA | NA | TypeD |
| 5 | NA | TypeF | NA |
| 6 | NA | TypeD | TypeD |

```
df$Group1 = factor((df$Group1))
df$Group2 = factor((df$Group2))
df$Group3 = factor((df$Group3))

str(df)
```

Result:

```
tibble [185 × 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ Group1: Factor w/ 7 levels "TypeA","TypeB",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Group2: Factor w/ 8 levels "TypeA","TypeB",..: NA 7 5 NA 6 4 8 NA NA 6 ...
 $ Group3: Factor w/ 15 levels "TypeA","TypeB",..: NA NA NA 4 NA 4 8 NA NA 4 ...
```

```
dput(df)
```

Result:

```
structure(list(Group1 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 1L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
2L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 
NA, 3L, NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
7L, 1L), levels = c("TypeA", "TypeB", "TypeC", "TypeD", "TypeE", 
"TypeF", "TypeG"), class = "factor"), Group2 = structure(c(NA, 
7L, 5L, NA, 6L, 4L, 8L, NA, NA, 6L, 1L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 1L, 2L, NA, NA, 2L, 1L, 6L, 1L, NA, 6L, 8L, 3L, 1L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 3L, NA, NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 5L, 3L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 4L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), levels = c("TypeA", "TypeB", 
"TypeC", "TypeD", "TypeE", "TypeF", "TypeH", "TypeI"), class = "factor"), 
    Group3 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, 4L, 8L, NA, NA, 
    4L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 9L, 6L, NA, 2L, 10L, NA, NA, 11L, 2L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, 8L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 5L, 1L, NA, 
    12L, NA, NA, 3L, 13L, NA, NA, 11L, 4L, 2L, 3L, NA, 1L, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 14L, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, 
    4L, NA, NA, 2L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 12L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 13L, 1L, 3L, NA, 
    NA, 6L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 11L, 
    NA, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    13L, 15L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), levels = c("TypeA", "TypeB", "TypeC", "TypeD", "TypeE", 
    "TypeG", "TypeH", "TypeI", "TypeJ", "TypeK", "TypeL", "TypeM", 
    "TypeN", "TypeO", "TypeS"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-185L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
> header(df)
Error in header(df) : could not find function "header"
> head(df)
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  Group1 Group2 Group3
  <fct>  <fct>  <fct> 
1 NA     NA     NA    
2 NA     TypeH  NA    
3 NA     TypeE  NA    
4 NA     NA     TypeD 
5 NA     TypeF  NA    
6 NA     TypeD  TypeD 
> df <- read_excel("C:/Users/rohan/OneDrive/Studies/Stats/Medical Analysis/whipples_Q5.xlsx")
> head(df)
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  Group1 Group2 Group3
  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
1 NA     NA     NA    
2 NA     TypeH  NA    
3 NA     TypeE  NA    
4 NA     NA     TypeD 
5 NA     TypeF  NA    
6 NA     TypeD  TypeD 
> df$Group1 = factor((df$Group1))
> df$Group2 = factor((df$Group2))
> df$Group3 = factor((df$Group3))
> 
> str(df)
tibble [185 × 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ Group1: Factor w/ 7 levels "TypeA","TypeB",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Group2: Factor w/ 8 levels "TypeA","TypeB",..: NA 7 5 NA 6 4 8 NA NA 6 ...
 $ Group3: Factor w/ 15 levels "TypeA","TypeB",..: NA NA NA 4 NA 4 8 NA NA 4 ...
> dput(df)
structure(list(Group1 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 1L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
2L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 
NA, 3L, NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
7L, 1L), levels = c("TypeA", "TypeB", "TypeC", "TypeD", "TypeE", 
"TypeF", "TypeG"), class = "factor"), Group2 = structure(c(NA, 
7L, 5L, NA, 6L, 4L, 8L, NA, NA, 6L, 1L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 1L, 2L, NA, NA, 2L, 1L, 6L, 1L, NA, 6L, 8L, 3L, 1L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 3L, NA, NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 5L, 3L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 4L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), levels = c("TypeA", "TypeB", 
"TypeC", "TypeD", "TypeE", "TypeF", "TypeH", "TypeI"), class = "factor"), 
    Group3 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, 4L, 8L, NA, NA, 
    4L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 9L, 6L, NA, 2L, 10L, NA, NA, 11L, 2L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, 8L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 5L, 1L, NA, 
    12L, NA, NA, 3L, 13L, NA, NA, 11L, 4L, 2L, 3L, NA, 1L, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 14L, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, 
    4L, NA, NA, 2L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 12L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 13L, 1L, 3L, NA, 
    NA, 6L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 11L, 
    NA, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    13L, 15L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), levels = c("TypeA", "TypeB", "TypeC", "TypeD", "TypeE", 
    "TypeG", "TypeH", "TypeI", "TypeJ", "TypeK", "TypeL", "TypeM", 
    "TypeN", "TypeO", "TypeS"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-185L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The complete script not broken down as above:

```
df <- read_excel("data.xlsx")
head(df)

df$Group1 = factor((df$Group1))
df$Group2 = factor((df$Group2))
df$Group3 = factor((df$Group3))

str(df)

dput(df)

contingency_table = table(df, useNA = "no")
print(contingency_table)

# Perform Chi-Square test
chi_square_result = chisq.test(contingency_table)
print(chi_square_result)
```

Comment: Could you show us `str(df)` just before the call to `table()`?  Or even better, `dput(df)` if that is small enough and you don't mind showing us your real data.

Comment: @user2554330 - I have edited the script to include ```str(df)``` and ```dput(df)```

Comment: You said `useNA = "no"`, but almost every row in `df` has an `NA` in it.  So your results aren't all zeros, but there are only 3 non-zero entries.  If you use `useNA = "always"`, then `<NA>` will be added as another level, and you'll see more non-zero results.  You'll still see a lot of zeros, so it will be hard to use a chi-square test:  the usual asymptotic approximation will be really poor.